# Passing data between controllers in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Referring to point #5 in the article below: 
http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

the author utilizes a object sharedDataService in both parent and child controllers.

```
//Do this instead
var Parent = function(sharedDataService){
  sharedDataService.updateName('foo');
};

var Child = function(messageService){
  sharedDataService.onNameChanged(this.nameChangedHandler);
};
```

Let let's assume that the function    sharedDataService.updateName('foo') is executed .. how does that trigger

sharedDataService.onNameChanged(this.nameChangedHandler) to be executed ?

What is the role of messageService here ?

Comment: I would say it looks like the author meant to inject `sharedDataService` instead of `messageService` into `Child`. Also, look at the `Observer` software design pattern, in case you haven't. That's what is being used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just one field you can use `$rootScope` to track the variable. If you want to pass data between two controllers, you can refer to this: 
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/
I prefer these methods.

Comment: that requires injection of $scope.. I believe the author of the article is promotion a method that does not necessarily require $scope.

Comment: i got that. but my point was. if it is just one variable then `$watch` on `$rootScope` is fine. if its the frequency is more then you might need something like that. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: wasn't quiet what I was looking for but I guess the angular pub-sub tech would do .. as long as we are not populating the $scope with other data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use pub/sub pattern totally. Actually, you can write simple "event firing" service that registers callback with specific event name and when an event is triggered, all callbacks will be called.